# reddit Picture of the posted link disappears

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, image, reddit

When I submit a link on Reddit, the picture of it (the one at the left) disappears after a while and the picture changes to the reddit logo with a camera and a question mark. Anyone have any clue how to fix this up?
you can find the examples here:
http://www.reddit.com/user/MemeAvenue/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That user account is shadowbanned which likely explains the disappearance of thumbnails to submissions the account posted. The typical reason for an account being shadowbanned is for spamming.

Overall, I believe this question is off-topic for SO.